# Bootstrap badge not rendering properly in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I am working on a project where badges are being used to denote the number of items in a certain category.  Here's a stripped down version of the code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button style="position: relative; min-width: 105px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-group-active">NEW <span class="badge label-bad-custom" style="position: absolute; top: -10px; right: 5px;">1</span>
    </button>
    <button style="position: relative; min-width: 105px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Old <span class="badge label-bad-custom" style="position: absolute; top: -10px; right: 5px;">2</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

In Chrome, it is rendering as desired:

[image: Badges in Chrome]

In IE, it is not:

[image: Badges in IE]

I am not a CSS wizard, but I have played around with padding/margins on the div/button/span to no avail.

I'm testing with IE 11.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
button {
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

the button should not be contained in table elements, to have this fix working

Comment: Excellent!  Worked perfectly!